# Grabbing Get option function from php file in plugin folders

Tags: wordpress

Really need some help i am making a plugin within the main plugin i have the code.

```
// Some Defaults
$bucket = 'music';

// Put our defaults in the "wp-options" table
add_option("isd-bucket", $bucket);
```

so thats great for me i no it adds to the database music.

the problem i am have is i need to pull that out off the database into another php file in my plugin folder.

in my playlist.php i have.

```
echo get_option("isd-bucket");
```

problem is when running this file i get.

Call to undefined function get_option() in

I understand this probably means i need to require other files so it intergrates with wordpress i have tried many options but cant get it to work plese help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to remove the extra white space (blank line) between the lines of code.

```
// Some Defaults
$bucket = 'music';
// Put our defaults in the "wp-options" table
add_option( "isd-bucket" , $bucket );
```